# Question on ellipse

Tags: conic-sections

A regular pentagon is inscribed in an ellipse with semi major axis 10 units. Then sum of all possible measures of the semi minor acis of the ellipse adds up to.

I don't exactly understand it. How to do?

Comment: If I get the problem correctly, you're expected to determine all possible positions of the pentagon inscribed in an ellipse with semi major axis measure $10$ and for each position find a semi minor axis length. Then sum semi minor axes lengths for all ellipses found.

Comment: Of course this could only make sense if the number of possible semi-minor axis values is finite.

Answer (score 3):

Five points determine a conic, so the "ellipse" is a circle.

Comment: I don't understand actually. After that?

Comment: How to do the possible sum

Comment: Well, the minor axis and the major axis of a circle are equal. They are radii, really. So there is only one possible legth for the minor axis.

Comment: So it's 5? Right?

Comment: Am I correct? I don't exactly understand.

Comment: Wait. It's 10 only as major and minor becomes equal here.